# Where is the Stellar daily transaction volume coming from?

Tags: transactions

Stellar has multiples in more daily transactions than Ethereum. Does anyone know for sure where this volume is coming from? I need to understand this before I continue something I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this alone is responsible but many people use XLM to transfer funds - i.e. from exchanges like Coinbase to elsewhere, to avoid high transfer fees since the network is fast and fees are so low.